# Send data to specific fragment of viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with a dynamic number of fragments. When the user enters data in a specific fragment and presses the "send" button, the method in the activity sends the entered data to the server, then the activity receives the response. How to send the received data to a specific fragment correctly? Thank you very much!

Fragment:

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView someText;
private Button sendTextButton;
private int pageId;
...
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    someText = view.findViewById(R.id.someText);
    sendTextButton = view.findViewById(R.id.sendTextButton);
    sendTextButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        ((MyListener)getActivity()).onSend(pageId, someText);
    });
    return view;
}
...
}
```

Activity class:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyListener {

private MyViewModel myViewModel;
...
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
    ...
    myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new ViewModelFactory(MyRepository.getInstance())).get(MyViewModel.class);

    myViewModel.sendResultResource().observe(this, data -> {
        switch (data.status) {
            case SUCCESS: {
                // how to return the result to the fragment?
                break;
            }
            case LOADING: {
                setLoading(true);
                break;
            }
            case ERROR: {
                showError(data.message);
                break;
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onSend(int pageId, String text) {
    myViewModel.sendAnswer(problemId, answers);
}

}
...
```

PagerAdapter:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private List<Data> dataList;
public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<Data> dataList) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.dataList = dataList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

@Override
public MyFragment getItem(int position) {
    return MyFragment.newInstance(position, dataList.get(position));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What about writing it in the bundle ? What do you think about it ?